# tlmgr cannot load TeX Live database

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, repositories, unix, freebsd

On freebsd 13 with the texlive-full port.
When I trying to set up `tlmgr` and check the repository with

```
tlmgr -repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet update --list
```

I get

```
tlmgr: Cannot load TeX Live database from https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

When I turn other explicit repos this stays the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately this was on a box of my former employer and I have no longer access to it.

Comment: You mean you can't remember how you solved it? Same problem here

Comment: Indeed, plus I can't look it up anymore. Sorry.